# Neo4j : Cloud or real hardware?

Tags: cloud, neo4j

I'm setting up a new infrasctructure for my company.

Considering the same machine specifications, does running neo4j in the cloud have the same performance as running it on real hardware ?
What are the pros and cons ?

Moreover, i'm running it on a windows instance for the moment, would it be better to run it on a Linux appliance ?

Thanks very much for all your answers !
Gouffe

Comment: How large do you expect your graph to be e.g. how many nodes and relationships? That's the most important factor. A single instance can easily deal with millions of nodes/relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i'm expecting to have billions of relationships and millions of nodes. But i'm sure that a single instance can deal that. My question is more about hardware, like for example network disks (in the cloud) against real hard drive.

Comment: I'd suggest you check out Heroku. Neo4j support seems to be great. Check out the [Neo4j Heroku page](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/heroku)

Comment: Once again thanks :) But i'm sorry to insist, i'm trying to compare what's comparable. I don't need a PaaS solution for the moment (even if it seems to be great indeed), i'm just comparing a dedicated server against a virtual machine on a cloud platform like AWS or Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real hardware is always faster,

virtual disks have some overhead, especially things like EBS. Nowadays there are several SSD offerings from cloud providers (and there is also provisioned I/O).

The virtual CPUs on cloud servers are often also not up to par, that might affect your ability to run graph queries quickly enough.

Still the best - write a test-data-generator for your graph and test it out. If the provisioned cloud infrastructure fits your performance requirements you're good to go.

Check out the Hardware sizing webinar for more details: https://vimeo.com/46049647

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's exactly the answer i was looking for !